# How to: place link to another kml file within a placemark

Tags: kml

I'm drawing the path of a ship sailing around the world, using a series of kml files, each containing multiple placemarks.

When I click on the last visible placemark, I DO NOT want to open a ballon containing text and a URL to the next file. Instead, I'd like GE to load and "flyto" the kml file that contains the next series of placemarks. So far, I haven't found a way to do this, so I'm wondering if it's possible. If so, how to? Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using KML in Google Earth. KML doesn't have an "onclick" method for Placemarks like this, when you click on a placemark, it opens up a balloon if there is one to be opened. If you want something more guided, you can do a [tour](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/touring) or you can open up a balloon that has a link with a ;flyto method added that takes you to a particular Placemark.

Comment: Oh well, I guess that's what I was fearing. I was trying to keep things super-simple, by NOT opening a ballon. I'd hoped there was some way to just add a "next segment" button near the end of the currently visible route. I figured for non-techie site visitors, that would be more intuitive than having to go over to the bottom of the list in the Places pane and check the "continue" box. Anyway, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: So two things: 1) You could make this part of a tour:https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/touring, more guided. or 2) You could do it as part of a NetworkLink that uses viewFormat to check the viewing location, and then load in new content. You'd have to have server support though: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#viewformat

Comment: For now, I have a NetworkLink as the last item in my Places list, with a "FlytoView" to the next kmz file. I guess that's the simplest way to do it for now. Too bad there's no way to put a "next" button (or simiilar) right in the 3D view though.